# When does @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) commit? - Follow up

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, hsqldb, container-managed

See this link:
[When does @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614364/when-does-transactionattributetransactionattributetype-requires-new-commit)

How can B be the correct answer? I would thought that a method annotated with REQUIRES_NEW would commit before the outer, suspended transaction, continues.

I'm asking about this because I have seen strange behaviors when it comes to transactions started with requires_new from another bean in a for-loop. Like if Aby calls bob in a for-loop. If one of these transactions is rolled back because of, for example a UniqueConstraintViolation, HSQLDB and db2 intermittently rolls back also the previous transactions, and intermittently only the transaction failed, and commits the others. And the behavior only changes when I restart my jboss. When a transaction fails and I get the behavior where also the previous transaction rolls back I also get a jdbcException: Connection closed in the next call from the loop.
So, first I wonder about the expected behavior of requires_new.  I'm using Hibernate, jboss 5, CMT, db2 and an in-memory HSQLDB(I've tried both 1.8 version and 2.2.9)
Thank You!

Comment: possible duplicate of [When does @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES\_NEW) commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614364/when-does-transactionattributetransactionattributetype-requires-new-commit)

Comment: Good question indeed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614364/when-does-transactionattributetransactionattributetype-requires-new-commit seems in contradiction with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817838/ejb-3-0-nested-transaction-requires-new

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found that this was the reason for the strange behavior

[jboss ignores requires_new after restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702602/jboss-ignores-requires-new-after-restart)

And in the link:

[When does @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614364/when-does-transactionattributetransactionattributetype-requires-new-commit)

the alternative a is the correct answer so it's the wrong answer in that post.