# How to know whether a Java method is using new JTA transaction or not?

Tags: java, oracle, transactions, ejb, jta

I am using container-managed transaction in my EJB application.

I have two stateless Java objects, which are class A and class B.

class B is instantiated in a method of class A.

Class B has two methods : method A and method B.

Method A is using transaction type = requires_new

Method B is using transaction type = required

There are 2 sql insertion statement in the two methods respectively. Method A and method B have different sql statement.

I find out that if there is any error happened in method B, everything in method A is rollback. This is not I want. I want everything in method A is committed even though method B raise System exception.

Thus, I don't think method A and B are running using a different transaction.

Can I know is there any way to system.out.println a boolean value showing a JTA transaction is new or not?

Thanks.

Below is the additional pseudo-code snippet to clarify my question above.

```
stateless class A{
  method(){
    Class b = new Class B();
    b.methodA();
    b.methodB():
  }
}

stateless class B(){
   method A(){ // There is an insert statement here.}
   method B(){ // There is another insert statement here.}

   //If anything happen in method B, only rollback B, don't rollback A.
 }
```

Comment: Transaction assosiated with the current thread could be obtained from TransactionManager (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/TransactionManager.html) and compared to another by it's hash code.

Comment: If methodA has Requires_new, it should't be rollbacked in case of problems in methodB, as it should already be commited. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10821117/3701228). What server are you running?

Comment: Hi Gas. I am using weblogic I highly doubt the problem is caused by weblogic server setting. My code should work.

Comment: Alex Erohin, as this is a container-type, not bean-type; I do not think we can obtain transactionManager object. I get error when called entityManager.getTranasaction();

Answer (score 0):

You are running the method B in the same transaction as that of method A. so failure of method B will rollback the insert happening in method A.

Run both the methods in different transactions if you don't want the method B to interfere with the method A.

If you are using Spring, can use [TransactionSynchronizationManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html) to find out the transaction level information.

Comment: Can I know how to run both in different transactions? I thought required_new and required are good enough to separate both into two transactions.

Comment: Anyway this is running in EJB, not Spring. Any idea? Many tqs.

Comment: In what sequence, you are calling methodA and methodB ?

Comment: Please see the additional psedo-code snippet above. I have just edited the question. tqs very much.